# How Do You Set Eclipse's Default Settings for When You Create New Workspaces?

Tags: eclipse

I work on a couple of large projects and have different workspaces for different projects I'm working on, to help with the speed of searching in Eclipse. I also have other workspaces for the different branches of these works spaces. When I create new workspaces, I notice that I have to update things like display of line numbers, decrease font size, and change of wrapping length.

I'm hoping there is a way to globally change these default values, so each new workspace will automatically get my preferred settings.

Answer (score 3):

Some settings can be exported/imported via wizard. Export/Import -> General -> Preferences.

Alot of your settings stored in: `../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/*`

(i.e.: `org.eclipse.ui.editors` contains the settings for line numbers)

You can copy&paste them.

Comment: I like this, is there a way to change the master settings though?

Comment: As far as i know, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3):

[Workspacemechanic](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/) can record any change you do in Eclipse preferences, and then it can apply those changes in other workspaces that doesn't meet them.

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/

By using workspace mechanic you can effectively override the global default preferences of Eclipse.
I'm using it to keep consistent fonts/color setup between different workspaces.